# Probability density transformation question

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, uniform-distribution

> Let X be a random variable that is uniformly distributed in (0,1). Find the
>   probability density function of Y = −ln X.

I got the solution $e^{-2y}$ for $y>0$, however the real solution is $e^{-y}$.

I followed the standard rule of $$f_Y(y) =f_X[g^{-1}(y)] \big |{d\over dy} g^{-1}(y) \big |  $$

and did $$f_X[g^{-1}(y)] = f_X[e^{-y}] = e^{-y}$$ because the random variable is just x,

and then $$\big |{d\over dy} g^{-1}(y) \big |=e^{-y} $$

so $$e^{-y}e^{-y} = e^{-2y} $$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It is $f_X(g^{-1}(y))$, not $f_Y()$.

Comment: So, doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: No, can you explain?

Comment: What is $f_X(x)$ ? Then what is $f_X(e^{-y})$?

Comment: I thought $f_X(x)$ is just $x$... Am I wrong?

Comment: $x$ is uniformly distributed in $(0, 1)$, so $f_X(x) \neq x$.

Comment: $f_X$ is a constant function by definition. If $f_X(x)=c$ from $0<x<1$, what is $c$?

Comment: Oh, I see it is 1. Thank you, I guess I was just confused about what uniformly distributed means.

Comment: Just a remark: another route is finding (for $y>0$): $F_Y(y)=P(-\ln X\leq y)=P(X\geq e^{-y})=1-e^{-y}$ and then differentiate.

Comment: Start with the CDF of $Y$ as $F_Y(y) = \text{Pr}\left[Y=-\ln(X)\leq y\right]$. This will give you $F_Y(y) = 1-F_X(e^{-y})$, where $F_X(x)$ is the CDF of $X$. All you need to do then is to substitute for $F_X(e^{-y})$, and then differentiate with respect to $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a basic uniform distribution, $f_X(x)=1$ for $x \in (0,1)$ and $0$ otherwise

So $f_X(g^{-1}(y))=1$ for $g^{-1}(y) \in (0,1)$, i.e. for $y \in (0,\infty)$, and $0$ otherwise

So $f_Y(y) =f_X[g^{-1}(y)] \left|{d\over dy} g^{-1}(y) \right| = \left|{d\over dy} g^{-1}(y) \right| = e^{-y}$ for $y \in (0,\infty)$, and $0$ otherwise